# Zonal statistics returns empty on Landsat 8 raster data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, landsat, zonal-statistics

I have derived surface temperature from the Landsat 8 thermal band 10.

My vector file is the following: [Small Areas City of Melbourne](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Economy/Small-Areas-for-Census-of-Land-Use-and-Employment-/gei8-3w86?_ga=2.53984104.1312781227.1523693094-1495328419.1508379828)

I want to calculate the mean, median and maximum temperature of the 14 different small areas that are within my spatial extend. I have already clipped the temperature raster file to the outline of the small areas vector layer.

Now I have tried Raster > Zonal statistics which simply does not return anything
and I have tried the Zonal Statistics from the plugins, which returns empty values.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a projection issue.

- Landsat 8: UTM Zone 55N (EPSG: 32655)
- Melbourne data: WGS84 (EPSG: 4326)

When I saved the polygon as a new shapefile (selecting EPSG 32655), Zonal statistics worked.

[image]

(Also I did confirm original file returned with blank cells by Zonal statistics.)